# Python files are not recognized by the Computer

Tags: python, windows, internet-explorer, operating-system, icons

I've installed Python in my system(Win 10) recently and through the Python IDLE, I wrote a simple code like

`print("Hello")` It works well, if I run it through the shell

But as soon as I save the file and then try to open it, is shows that the program is not recognized by the computer. It gives me options to choose the app that can run the program. The icon is the "Internet Explorer" which is completely irrelevant.

Yes, I've added Python's path and Script's path into the system variables, but still no luck. I again uninstalled and re-installed python, that too didn't work. I even restarted the system, still no luck.

I'm using a Win 10 machine.

Comment: What extension did you choose for the file? Do you know how to set default executables to be run for specific extensions in your OS?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan the extension I saved is .py, how do I set executables?

Comment: I personally never owned Win 10, but this link will hopefully help you. Just find `.py` and set the default opener to be your `python.exe` wherever that is. Here's the link: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477

Comment: I also tested it in win10 and it works fine. So I am not sure if there is a problem with your environment configuration. Can you use `where python` in the command line to find the corresponding path? Something like this: [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmrCl.png).

Comment: @CaptainTrojan I tried that method, but I can only manage to open it with notepad. There wasn't any choice for python.

Comment: @XudongPeng Yeah, the path was like
"C:/Users/Vishal/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe"

Comment: @VishalRam You can also try righ-clicking on the file, selecting "open with...", "choose default program" and "more options", then you gotta insert the path in the above comment. Try that out, see if that helps!

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Thanks for your Help! I finally figured it out. And yeah, your method works just fine.